# How to exit a node script in order to 'complete' a kubernetes job

Tags: kubernetes, jobs, keda

I'm currently using `Process.exit(0)` to exit my node.js script that is running inside a docker container as a kubernetes Job. This doesn't seem to be 'completing' the job which stops the KEDA pod autoscaler from removing the pod.

How would I exit the node script in a way that will be considered to be a 'completion' of the job?

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong but it seems to me this is the `node`+`docker PID1` issue.

Please check very useful [Avoid running nodejs as PID 1 under the docker image](https://developpaper.com/avoid-running-nodejs-as-pid-1-under-the-docker-image/) article that explains what is happening in the details.

---

> It turns out that nodejs cannot receive signals and process them
> properly (if it is running with PID 1). Signal refers to SIGTERM,
> SIGINT and other kernel signals.
>
> If you run nodejs as PID 1, the following code will not work at all:

```
process.on('SIGTERM', function onSigterm() {
  // do the cleaning job, but it wouldn't
  process.exit(0);
});
```

> As a result, you will get a zombie process that will be forced to
> terminate by sigkill signal, which means that your “clean up” code
> will not be called at all.

---

Best practices recommend to avoid to run nodejs as PID 1, so running inside docker can cause unexpected behaviors.

Talking about `docker`, it is possible to use `--init` flag that

> will wrap your process with a small init system that will take
> advantage of all kernel signals to its subprocesses and ensure that
> all orphaned processes are harvested.

For kubernetes you dont have such an option, however there is a trick you can try: you can use [dumb-init](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init) as [entrypoint in your image](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init#usage).

```
# Runs "/usr/bin/dumb-init -- /my/script --with --args"
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/dumb-init", "--"]

# or if you use --rewrite or other cli flags
# ENTRYPOINT ["dumb-init", "--rewrite", "2:3", "--"]

CMD ["/my/script", "--with", "--args"]
```

> dumb-init is a simple process supervisor and init system designed to
> run as PID 1 inside minimal container environments (such as Docker).
> It is deployed as a small, statically-linked binary written in C.
>
> Lightweight containers have popularized the idea of running a single
> process or service without normal init systems like systemd or
> sysvinit. However, omitting an init system often leads to incorrect
> handling of processes and signals, and can result in problems such as
> containers which can't be gracefully stopped, or leaking containers
> which should have been destroyed.
>
> dumb-init enables you to simply prefix your command with dumb-init. It
> acts as PID 1 and immediately spawns your command as a child process,
> taking care to properly handle and forward signals as they are
> received.